# Using data parameters in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, data-driven-tests

Very novice level question. What's the easiest way of opening several websites one by one after reading site names from an external file.
In the example below; I want to replace values of web URL from file and screemshot file name in same way.

Example script:

```
From selenium import webdriver
Driver=webdriver.ie(...driverpath)

Driver.get("facebook.com")
Driver.get_screenshot_as_file("facebook.png")

Driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your code trials of `reading site names from an external file` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I have used json for storing the websites, a simple text file will do as well

```
import json
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

with open('path to json file', encoding='utf-8') as s:
    data = json.loads(s.read())

for site in data['sites']:
    driver = Chrome('path to chrome driver')
    driver.get(data['sites'][site])
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(site + '.png')
    driver.close()
```

json file

```
{

    "sites": {

        "facebook": "https://www.facebook.com/",
        "google": "https://www.google.com/",
        "wikipedia": "https://www.wikipedia.org/"

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Satish. It worked. Got some small errors here and there due to spance and indent but it did the job for for me. Thanks again.